# A kind of asymptote for generalized alternating series

Tags: real-analysis

This is an interesting problem (Problem 1.6.1) from the book "Problems in Real Analysis" by  Radulescu et al.:

> Let $\sum b_n a_n$ be a convergent series, where $a_1 \geq a_2 \geq \ldots \geq 0$, and $b_i = \pm 1$ for all $i$.
>
> Show that $(b_1 + b_2 + \ldots + b_n)a_n$ converges to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

I'd love to see some solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simple proof, without to many technical steps, with the help of Kronecker's lemma. In fact, it is a special case of Kronecker's lemma.

> If $\alpha_k \in \mathbb{R}$ and $(\beta_k)_k$ is an increasing sequence of positive real numbers with $\beta_k \rightarrow \infty$ such that  $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_k$ is convergent, then $\frac{1}{\beta_n} \sum_{k=1}^n \beta_k \alpha_k \rightarrow 0$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Proof: Write $S_n := \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k$, then we have
$$\frac{1}{\beta_n} \sum_{k=1}^n \beta_k \alpha_k = \frac{1}{\beta_n} \sum_{k=1}^n \beta_k (S_k -S_{k-1}) = S_n - \frac{1}{\beta_n} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (\beta_{k+1}-\beta_k) S_k  $$
Since $S_n \rightarrow s$, it remains to prove that $ \frac{1}{\beta_n} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (\beta_{k+1}-\beta_k) S_k \rightarrow s$. Take $|S_n -s| < \varepsilon$ for all $n \ge N$. Then we have for all $n > N$ that
\begin{align}
 &\frac{1}{\beta_n} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (\beta_{k+1}-\beta_k) S_k-(1- \beta_1/\beta_n)s \\
 =& \frac{1}{\beta_n} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} (\beta_{k+1}-\beta_k) (S_k-s)  \\
 =&\frac{1}{\beta_n} \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} (\beta_{k+1}-\beta_k) (S_k-s) +  \frac{1}{\beta_n} \sum_{k=N}^{n-1} (\beta_{k+1}-\beta_k) (S_k-s)
\end{align}
We have $(1- \beta_1/\beta_n)s \rightarrow s$ and $\frac{1}{\beta_n} \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} (\beta_{k+1}-\beta_k) (S_k-s) \rightarrow 0$ for fixed $N$. On the other hand
$$\left|\frac{1}{\beta_n} \sum_{k=N}^{n} (\beta_{k+1}-\beta_k) (S_k-s) \right| \le \varepsilon \frac{1}{\beta_n} (\beta_n - \beta_N) \le \varepsilon M  $$
This proves Kronecker's lemma.

Now, we would like to apply the lemma as follows. Our first observation is that $a_n \rightarrow 0$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$, because $|a_n b_b| = |a_n|$ and $b_n a_n \rightarrow 0$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$, since the sum converges. Thus, we can take $\beta_n = a_k^{-1}$ and this sequence satisfies Kronecker's lemma, because $(a_n)_n$ is also decreasing. Since $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (b_k a_k)$ is convergent (we take $\alpha_k = b_k a_k$), we get that 
$$a_m \sum_{k=1}^m b_k = \frac{1}{\beta_m} \sum_{k=1}^m \alpha_k \beta_k \rightarrow 0.$$

Comment: Why does a $k$ fulfilling your inequality (2) exist?

Comment: We have $n_k \rightarrow \infty$ for $k \rightarrow \infty$. On the other hand, we can use that the series convegences, i.e. is a Cauchy-sequence. Thus, for any $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ with $|\sum_{i=n}^m b_i a_i| < \varepsilon$ for all $m >n \ge N$. Specially, we can take (for $k$ large enough) $n = n_k$ and $m = (n_{k+1}-1) \wedge m$.

Comment: I can see why due to Cauchy it has to be $< \epsilon$, but why is the left part of the inequality correct? I'm not sure why $n_{k+1} \wedge (m-n_k)a_m$ has to be smaller than the sum

Comment: Note that $(a_n)$ is decreasing and that we have $b_i =1$ or $b_i = -1$ for all terms in the sum. Thus the sum is just $\left| \sum_{i=n_l}^{(n_{l+1}-1) \wedge m} a_i \right| \ge a_m [(n_{l+1}-1) \wedge m-n_l+1]$.

Comment: But why is $b_i$'s sign fixed for all terms in the sum? Isn't your $m$ unbounded? You can pick it high enough that the $b_i$s start changing signs, no?

Comment: I have added a complete proof, where I apply the Kronecker-lemma. It is more straightforward than the first attempt.

Comment: Very interesting, I haven't heard of this lemma!